Why does swift navigation list with button open a sheet multiple times instead of just once?
TLDR: In the following code, clicking on the button from the top level ContentView opens multiple sheets, and then when closing the sheet it gets triggered again; yet clicking it from the RowView only opens one sheet. How can I only open one sheet from ContentView?
Here's a simple version of what I have: A navigation stack with a list of items, each of which has a button that will open a sheet. When the sheet is pulled up, it runs a task to call a web service and retrieve some data to display.
The issue is, according to my debugging, multiple sheets are being opened, each of which runs the task, and some fail due to the duplicate call. The way I'd like to fix this issue is to have the sheet only appear once. How can I get this to work?

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Hello")
                } label: {
                    RowView(textToShow: "Text 1")
                }
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Hello")
                } label: {
                    RowView(textToShow: "Text 2")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RowView: View {
    var textToShow: String
    @State private var showingPopover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
        
        Button(action: {
            //showingPopover = true
            print("Button pressed")
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName:"doc.text")
                .imageScale(.large)
                
        })
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Button tapped")
            showingPopover = true
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingPopover, content: {
            PopupView(textToShow: textToShow)
                .onAppear {
                    print("Sheet appeared")
                }
        })
    }
}

struct PopupView: View {
    var textToShow: String
    @State private var loading = true
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if loading {
                HStack{
                    ProgressView()
                    Text("Loading...")
                }
            } else {
                Text(textToShow)
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            print("Loading")
            loading = false
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

#Preview {
    RowView(textToShow: "Text 1")
}

Clicking the button, and then closing the sheet leads to the following in the console:

Button tapped
Loading
Sheet appeared
Loading
Sheet appeared
Loading
Sheet appeared

I've tried using a state variable to capture when the popover has already been opened, and then for the sheet content to only display if the popover hasn't been opened; I tried setting the binding variable to true only on the first tap gesture, but that's not the fix either.
Based on another similar question, I think I need to move the sheet up, which is a little tricky then to capture the row-specific text (I've been using swift for like 2 weeks now? so not completely used to it) but I think that could work
I'm expecting only a single sheet to load and run its task.

What version of Xcode and iOS are you using? Tried your code out in Xcode 14.3.1 and I'm not seeing the issue. I can try Xcode 15 if that's applicable to you.
BTW you should wrap your RowView in a view like an HStack or a VStack, but it doesn't look like this is related to your issue at all.

Thank you! I'm using Xcode 15.3 and iPhone 15. Btw I made some small code updates to better reflect my actual use case (each row will have a variable for text to show in the popup)

ok I'll give it a whirl over on another machine — EDIT: yes I am getting the same thing on Xcode 15.2, though just logs appear 2x instead of 3x.

Ok thanks for verifying that it's new to this version of Xcode. For me, the 3x was when I dismiss the sheet (seems like a weird time for sheet onAppear to be called)

oh, then yes same thing on my end. Seems like it might be a bug, though in general probably tricky to use onAppear for certain types of logic.

Not sure if applicable but you may want to use .task instead. EDIT: oh but that also seems to be called multiple times :S
Note this problem seems to be specific to views inside a NavigationLink — remove that and it doesn't happen (though obviously if you need navigation it's not that simple).

Oh and I should mention that although I am seeing duplicate logs like you, I have not seen it present multiple sheets at once.

Yeah the multiple sheets isn't evident with this example I think, but I think it's occurring because when I run my actual code where each sheet runs a web service call, one sheet shows the call results (according to debug)  while the second fails (trying to make the call at the same time) and shows the default "Loading" text. I'm trying to move the sheet up and I think that will work, just a bit tricky for me to work with Bindings

Ok I think I found a solution: by moving the sheet up to the NavigationStack, it only appears once. To make the comment come from a variable that is Row-dependent, I just use a binding variable. In this case I used isPresented and a separate variable, but in my own case I think I will use the item input for a sheet.
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingPopover: Bool = false
    @State var textToShow: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Hello")
                } label: {
                    RowView(showingPopover: $showingPopover, textToShow: $textToShow, textValue: "Text 1")
                }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("Hello")
                } label: {
                    RowView(showingPopover: $showingPopover, textToShow: $textToShow, textValue: "Text 2")
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showingPopover, onDismiss: {
            print("Sheet dismissed")
            showingPopover = false
            textToShow = ""
        }, content: {
                PopupView(textToShow: textToShow)
                    .onAppear {
                        print("Popup appeared")
                    }
        })
    }
    
}

struct RowView: View {
    @Binding var showingPopover: Bool
    @Binding var textToShow: String
    var textValue: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello")
        
        Button(action: {
            //showingPopover = true
            print("Button pressed")
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName:"doc.text")
                .imageScale(.large)
                
        })
        .onTapGesture {
            print("Button tapped")
            textToShow = textValue
            showingPopover = true
        }
        
    }
}

struct PopupView: View {
    var textToShow: String
    @State private var loading = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if loading {
                HStack{
                    ProgressView()
                    Text("Loading...")
                }
            } else {
                Text(textToShow)
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            print("Loading")
            loading = false
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

